# Maintaining integrity between 3 tables when reference could be through or direct

Tags: sql-server, database-design, data-integrity

Say we have the following 3 tables:

```
tUsers (ID, name, countryID, regionID)
------
1  |  Joe  |  1   |  1
2  |  Sue  | NULL |  2
3  |  Bob  |  2   |  NULL
4  |  Amy  | NULL |  NULL

tCountries (ID, name, regionID)
------
1  |  USA   |  1
2  |  China |  3

tRegions (ID, name)
------
1  |  North America
2  |  Central America
3  |  East Asia
4  |  Europe
```

Is there a way from the DB to prevent a user from having mismatched Country/Region while still allowing one or both to be NULL?  For example, the query `UPDATE tUsers SET regionID=4 WHERE ID = 3` would fail since Bob's country is China which is not in region Europe.

Comment: What if you put the region FK on country instead of User?  The user would pick a country which would automatically belong to the correct region.

Comment: @datagod The problem is the user can choose to only provide region, which means country would be NULL.  I suppose you could make a null entry in `tCountry` for every entry in `tRegion` but that seems excessive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3 foreign keys version

```
create table tRegions (
  ID int not null primary key, 
  name  varchar(20)
); 

create table tCountries (
  ID int not null primary key, 
  name varchar(20), 
  regionID int, 
  --any superset of PK is undoubtly UNIQUE
  constraint cu1 unique (ID, regionID),
  foreign key (regionID) references tRegions(ID)
  );

create table tUsers (
 ID int not null primary key, 
 name varchar(20), 
 countryID int ,
 regionID int,
 foreign key (regionID) references tRegions(ID),
 foreign key (countryID) references tCountries(ID),
 foreign key (countryID,regionID) references tCountries(ID,regionID )
)

insert tRegions (ID, name)
values
(1,'North America'),
(2,'Central America'),
(3,'East Asia'),
(4,'Europe') 

insert tCountries(ID, name, regionId)
values
(1,'USA',1),
(2,'China',3)

insert tUsers (ID, name, countryID, regionId)
values
(1,'Joe', 1  ,1),
(2,'Sue',NULL,2),
(3,'Bob', 2  ,NULL),
(4,'Amy',NULL,NULL)

go
--OK
update tUsers set RegionId=3
where ID=3
select * from tUsers
go
--fails
update tUsers set CountryId=2
where ID=2
select * from tUsers
```

Comment: I red quite some documentation on sites about databases and design and this is the first time i see it was even possible. Isn't this not really widely known or did i just no got on the rights sites ?

Comment: @Walfrat Most probably such sites do exist, but i have no link at hand. And _Any superset of PK is UNIQUE_ is just one of the Relational model facts. Applying it to your data comes rather from practice.  Note it will cost you extra index.

Comment: Yes it is, but the part i didn't know was that you can apply foreign keys to more than one field, i saw lot of example about primary composite keys, unique composite keys, index on multiple columns, but never foreign key on multiple columns, so it never crossed my mind i could do it. Of course since you need 3 foreign key to handle special case, this cost a bit more when you modify data. I already applied it to my model i'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than making sure *tUsers.regionID* matches *tCountries.regionID* when *tUsers.countryID* is set, you could simply prevent both *countryID* and *regionID* from being set simultaneously on a row by adding a check constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE
  dbo.tUsers
ADD
  CONSTRAINT CK_CountryRegion
  CHECK (countryID IS NULL OR regionID IS NULL)
;
```

Now, if a country is set, you can derive the region through *tCountries* – either like this:

```
SELECT
  UserName = u.name,
  Country  = c.name,
  Region   = r.name,
FROM
  dbo.tUsers AS u
  LEFT JOIN dbo.tCountries AS c ON u.countryID = c.ID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.tRegions AS r ON r.ID IN (u.regionID, c.regionID)
;
```

or like this:

```
SELECT
  UserName = u.name,
  Country  = c.name,
  Region   = ISNULL(ru.name, rc.name),
FROM
  dbo.tUsers AS u
  LEFT JOIN dbo.tRegions AS ru ON ru.ID = u.regionID
  LEFT JOIN
    dbo.tCountries AS c
    INNER JOIN dbo.tRegions AS rc ON rc.ID = c.regionID
  ON u.countryID = c.ID
;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to ensure *tUsers.regionID* matches *tCountries.regionID* when *tUsers.countryID* is set if you agree to introduce some redundancy in the form of an additional unique constraint (and the index supporting it).

The idea is as follows:

- Make sure *tCountries.ID* and *tRegions.ID* are the PKs of their respective tables.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE
    dbo.tCountries
  ADD
    CONSTRAINT PK_tCountries
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  ;

  ALTER TABLE
    dbo.tRegions
  ADD
    CONSTRAINT PK_tRegions
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  ;
  ```
- Have *tCountries.regionID* reference *tRegions.ID* (not directly relevant to this solution, but just for completeness).

  ```
  ALTER TABLE
    dbo.tCountries
  ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_tCountries_regionID
    FOREIGN KEY (regionID) REFERENCES tRegions (ID)
  ;
  ```
- Have *tUsers.countryID* reference *tCountries.ID*.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE
    dbo.tUsers
  ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_tUsers_countryID
    FOREIGN KEY (countryID) REFERENCES tCountries (ID)
  ;
  ```
- Have *tUsers.regionID* reference *tRegions.ID*.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE
    dbo.tUsers
  ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_tUsers_regionID
    FOREIGN KEY (regionID) REFERENCES tRegions (ID)
  ;
  ```
- Create a unique constraint on (*ID*, *regionID*) in *tCountries*.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE
    dbo.tCountries
  ADD
    CONSTRAINT UQ_tCountries_IDregionID
    UNIQUE (ID, regionID)
  ;
  ```
- Have (*countryID*, *regionID*) in *tUsers* reference (*ID*, *regionID*) in *tCountries*.

  ```
  ALTER TABLE
    dbo.tUsers
  ADD
    CONSTRAINT FK_tUsers_countryIDregionID
    FOREIGN KEY (countryID, regionID) REFERENCES tCountries (ID, regionID)
  ;
  ```

When either country or region is not set, the composite foreign key will not be checked because of the NULL(s) – similarly to how a single-column foreign key is not checked if it is null. If both columns are set, however, all three foreign keys will work, preventing the discrepancy in the regions between *tUsers* and *tCountries*.